# VScode remote SSH to a new Vagrant Box ending in error

Tags: ubuntu, visual-studio-code, ssh, vagrant, vscode-remote-ssh

I have setup a new vagrant box and I can connect to it using Vagrant SSH comand normally but I can't connect using reomte SSH from Visual Code.
Both Vagrant Boxes are Ubuntu(bento) boxes.
I've added second host to the ssh.config file in the very similar way as for previous host but this does not work. Is it because it uslo use loopback adress and this is not really allowed?
I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

My SSH config in VS Code:
ssh.config:

```
Host default
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User panda
    Port 2222
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    IdentityFile C:/DevOps/VagrantRepo/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    LogLevel FATAL
Host h00jraq
    HostName 127.0.0.1
    User h00jraq
    Port 2223
    UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
    StrictHostKeyChecking no
    PasswordAuthentication no
    IdentityFile C:/DevOps/Vagrant_moja_vmka/.vagrant/machines/default/virtualbox/private_key
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    LogLevel FATAL
```

The Log from VS Code:

```
[17:17:23.439] Log Level: 2
[17:17:23.441] remote-ssh@0.70.0
[17:17:23.441] win32 x64
[17:17:23.442] SSH Resolver called for "ssh-remote+h00jraq", attempt 1
[17:17:23.442] "remote.SSH.useLocalServer": false
[17:17:23.442] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:17:23.442] "remote.SSH.remotePlatform": {"default":"linux"}
[17:17:23.442] "remote.SSH.path": undefined
[17:17:23.442] "remote.SSH.configFile": undefined
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.useFlock": true
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.lockfilesInTmp": false
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.localServerDownload": auto
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.remoteServerListenOnSocket": false
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.showLoginTerminal": false
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.defaultExtensions": []
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.loglevel": 2
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.serverPickPortsFromRange": {}
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.enableDynamicForwarding": true
[17:17:23.443] "remote.SSH.serverInstallPath": {}
[17:17:23.444] SSH Resolver called for host: h00jraq
[17:17:23.444] Setting up SSH remote "h00jraq"
[17:17:23.456] Using commit id "f80445acd5a3dadef24aa209168452a3d97cc326" and quality "stable" for server
[17:17:23.458] Install and start server if needed
[17:17:24.634] Checking ssh with "ssh -V"
[17:17:24.660] > OpenSSH_for_Windows_8.1p1, LibreSSL 3.0.2

[17:17:24.663] Running script with connection command: ssh -T -D 49607 h00jraq bash
[17:17:24.664] Terminal shell path: C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[17:17:24.845] > ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe
[17:17:24.845] Got some output, clearing connection timeout
[17:17:26.858] > The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[17:17:28.113] "install" terminal command done
[17:17:28.113] Install terminal quit with output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exeThe process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[17:17:28.114] Received install output: ]0;C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exeThe process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe.
[17:17:28.114] Resolver error: Error: The process tried to write to a nonexistent pipe
    at Function.Offline (c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:430476)
    at c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:428026
    at Object.t.handleInstallOutput (c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:428404)
    at Object.t.tryInstall (c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:524212)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
    at async c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:487216
    at async Object.t.withShowDetailsEvent (c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:490561)
    at async Object.t.resolve (c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:488295)
    at async c:\Users\filip\.vscode\extensions\ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh-0.70.0\out\extension.js:1:564197
[17:17:28.116] ------
```